# i created a model recognise digits and i have an accuracy of 95% but the model always predicts [0] for any image

Tags: python, tensorflow

I created a model to recognize digits from images. The images have dark background and white pixels that represents the digits (its a black and white image). I have 95% accuracy but any image that is given to predict, it  always predicts [0]:

```
DATADIR = "./abc"
catg = ['data_aug_0','data_aug_1','data_aug_2','data_aug_3','data_aug_4','data_aug_5','data_aug_6','data_aug_7','data_aug_8','data_aug_9']
training_data=[]
img_size = 32
img_size2 = 32
def create_training_data():
    for category in catg:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
        class_num = catg.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:#if some images are broken do this
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(img_size,img_size2))
                training_data.append([new_array,class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass
create_training_data()
print(len(training_data))

trainX = [] #features
trainy = [] #labels

for features , label in training_data:
    trainX.append(features)
    trainy.append(label)

trainX = np.array(trainX).reshape(-1,img_size,img_size2,1)
trainy = np.array(trainy)

trainy = to_categorical(trainy, num_classes=10)

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout , Activation , Flatten , Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(16,(5,5),input_shape = (32,32,1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2,2),strides = 2))
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2),strides = 2))

model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2),strides = 2))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units = 10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001,beta_1=0.9,beta_2=0.999,epsilon = None,decay = 0.0,amsgrad = False)

model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = adam, metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(trainX,trainy,batch_size=16 ,epochs=10,validation_split = 0.1)
# Loss Curves
plt.figure(figsize=[8,6])
plt.plot(history.history['loss'],'r',linewidth=3.0)
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'],'b',linewidth=3.0)
plt.legend(['Training loss', 'Validation Loss'],fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Epochs ',fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Loss',fontsize=16)
plt.title('Loss Curves',fontsize=16)

# Accuracy Curves
plt.figure(figsize=[8,6])
plt.plot(history.history['acc'],'r',linewidth=3.0)
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'],'b',linewidth=3.0)
plt.legend(['Training Accuracy', 'Validation Accuracy'],fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Epochs ',fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Accuracy',fontsize=16)
plt.title('Accuracy Curves',fontsize=16)

#predicting a single image ' [0] == dog  and [1] == cat'
img1 = cv2.imread('./testing_prediction/2.png',0)
img1 = cv2.resize(img1,(50,50))
plt.imshow(img1,'gray')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
img = image.img_to_array(img1)
img = img/255
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

images = np.vstack([img])
classes = model.predict_classes(images, batch_size=10)
print(classes)
```

I always get 0 for prediction, even though I tried to predict an image already trained on. for exemple if i try an image with written digit 2 on it, it predicts it as a 0. if its an 8, its predicts as 0

Answer (score 0):

Consider below points:

- You are resizing your training images to `32 x 32`, while testing data to `50 x 50`. Both needs to be the same.
- You forgot to normalize your training image data. But, you are normalizing the test data.

  ```
  img = img/255
  ```

You should preprocess you test image data the same way you did with training data.